# How to evaulate $\int_0^{\infty}\frac{\ln x}{\sqrt{x}(x^2+a^2)^2}$ using contour integration

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

I'm asked to calculate the following integral for which $0 \neq a \in \mathbb{R}$:

$$\int_0^{\infty}\frac{\ln x}{\sqrt{x}(x^2+a^2)^2}$$

I'm confused about which contour I should use, whether it should be a semi-circle deformed to avoid the origin, or a keyhole contour based on a similar question I found here: [Calculating $\int_0^{\infty } \frac{\ln (x)}{\sqrt{x} \left(a^2+x^2\right)^2} \, \mathrm{d}x$ using contour integration](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1842497/calculating-int-0-infty-frac-ln-x-sqrtx-lefta2x2-right2) (but this question did not go into detail about how the integration was carried out using the keyhole contour)

Also, after deciding on which contour to use, how do I proceed from there to evaluate this integral? I know that I would eventually have to use the Residue Theorem but how do I isolate the part of the contour only going from $0$ to $\infty$?

Comment: Why the deliberate duplicate?

Comment: The question I linked to didn't address how to use the keyhole contour to evaluate the integral; it focused on using a different contour

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We integrate with $a$ a positive real

$$f(z) = \frac{\mathrm{Log}(z)}{(z-ai)^2 (z+ai)^2}
\exp(-1/2\times \mathrm{Log}(z))$$

around a  keyhole contour  with the  slot on  the positive  real axis,
which  is also  where  the  branch cut  of  the  logarithm is  located
(argument of  the logarithm is  between $0$  and $2\pi$). Now  for the
large circle we get $\lim_{R\to\infty} 2\pi R \log R / \sqrt{R} /R^4 =
0$ so  there is no  contribution in the  limit.  For the  small circle
around the  origin we find  $\lim_{\epsilon\to\ 0} 2\pi  \epsilon \log
\epsilon /  \sqrt\epsilon /a^4 = 0$  so there is no  contribution here
either.

We get for the upper line segment

$$\int_0^\infty \frac{\log x}{(x^2+a^2)^2}
\exp(-1/2\times \log x) \; dx$$

which is  our target  integral, call  it $J$.  The lower  line segment
contributes

$$-\int_0^\infty \frac{\log x + 2\pi i}{(x^2+a^2)^2}
\exp(-1/2\times \log x) \exp(-1/2\times 2\pi i) \; dx
\\ = \int_0^\infty \frac{\log x + 2\pi i}{(x^2+a^2)^2}
\exp(-1/2\times \log x) \; dx
\\ = J + 2\pi i \int_0^\infty \frac{1}{(x^2+a^2)^2}
\exp(-1/2\times \log x) \; dx = J + 2\pi i K$$

where $J$ and $K$ are real numbers. We thus have

$$2J + 2\pi i K = 2\pi i  \mathrm{Res}_{z=ai} f(z)
+ 2\pi i  \mathrm{Res}_{z=-ai} f(z)$$

or

$$J + \pi i K = \pi i  \mathrm{Res}_{z=ai} f(z)
+ \pi i  \mathrm{Res}_{z=-ai} f(z)$$

With this  setup we  do not actually  need to compute  $K$ as  it must
correspond  to the  imaginary part  of the  contribution from  the two
residues. We get for the first residue at $z=ai$ the derivative

$$\frac{1}{z} \frac{1}{(z+ai)^2} \exp(-1/2\times \mathrm{Log}(z))
-2 \mathrm{Log}(z) 
\frac{1}{(z+ai)^3} \exp(-1/2\times \mathrm{Log}(z))
\\ + \mathrm{Log}(z) \frac{1}{(z+ai)^2} 
\exp(-1/2\times \mathrm{Log}(z)) \times -\frac{1}{2} \frac{1}{z}.$$

With the branch of the logarithm we find $\mathrm{Log}(ai) =
\log a + \pi i/2$, getting

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{a}} \exp(-\pi i/4)
\\ \times \left(\frac{1}{ai} \times - \frac{1}{4 a^2}
+ (2\log a + \pi i) \frac{1}{8 i a^3}
+ (\log a + \pi i/2) \times - \frac{1}{4 a^2} 
\times -\frac{1}{2 ai}\right)
\\ = \frac{1}{\sqrt{a}} \exp(-\pi i/4) \frac{1}{8i a^3}
(3\log a + 3\pi i/2 - 2).$$

We also have $\mathrm{Log}(-ai) = \log a + 3 \pi i/2$, getting
for the second residue at $z=-ai$

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{a}} \exp(-3\pi i/4)
\\ \times \left(- \frac{1}{ai} \times - \frac{1}{4 a^2}
- (2\log a + 3\pi i) \frac{1}{8 i a^3}
+ (\log a + 3\pi i/2) \times - \frac{1}{4 a^2} 
\times \frac{1}{2 ai}\right)
\\ = \frac{1}{\sqrt{a}} \exp(-3\pi i/4) \frac{1}{8i a^3}
(- 3\log a - 9\pi i/2 + 2).$$

With $\exp(-\pi i/4) = 
\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} - i \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$
and $\exp(-3\pi i/4) = 
-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} - i \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$

and factoring out $\frac{1}{\sqrt{a}} \frac{1}{8i a^3}$
we get three contributions, which are

$$\sqrt{2} (3\log a - 2) + 3\pi i (\sqrt{2} + i\sqrt{2}/2)$$

Combine these and multiply by $\pi i$ to get

$$\frac{\pi}{8\sqrt{a} a^3}
(\sqrt{2} (3\log a - 2) + 3\pi i (\sqrt{2} + i\sqrt{2}/2)).$$

We extract the real part as promised and obtain

$$\frac{\sqrt{2}\pi}{8\sqrt{a} a^3}
(3\log a - 2 - 3\pi/2)$$

or

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #00A000]{
\frac{\pi}{4\sqrt{2} a^{7/2}}
\left(3\log a - 2 - \frac{3}{2}\pi\right).}$$

matching the result by @Jack D'Aurizio.

As a bonus we have shown that

$$\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{\sqrt{x} (x^2+a^2)^2} dx
= \frac{1}{\pi} \frac{\pi}{8\sqrt{a} a^3} 3\sqrt{2}\pi 
= \frac{3\pi}{4\sqrt{2} a^{7/2}}.$$

Answer (score 2):

$\phantom{a}$ Dear audience, this is the new episode of *Feynman's trick versus contour integration*.

---

Our starting point is 
$$\forall \alpha\in(-1,1),\qquad \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{x^\alpha}{1+x^2}\,dx =\frac{\pi}{2\cos\tfrac{\pi\alpha}{2}}\tag{1}$$
which is a consequence of the substitution $\frac{1}{1+x^2}=u$, Euler's Beta function and the reflection formula for the $\Gamma$ function. We may introduce a further parameter $K>0$ and state
$$\forall \alpha\in(-1,1),\forall K>0,\qquad \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{x^\alpha}{K+x^2}\,dx =\frac{\pi K^{\frac{\alpha-1}{2}}}{2\cos\tfrac{\pi\alpha}{2}}\tag{2}$$
then differentiate both sides with respect to $K$:
$$\forall \alpha\in(-1,1),\forall K>0,\qquad \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{x^\alpha}{(K+x^2)^2}\,dx =\frac{\pi(1-\alpha) K^{\frac{\alpha-3}{2}}}{4\cos\tfrac{\pi\alpha}{2}}.\tag{3}$$
Let us differentiate both sides with respect to $\alpha$ (it is more practical to exploit $\frac{df}{dx}=f(x)\cdot\frac{d}{dx}\log f(x)$ to manipulate the RHS):
$$\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{x^\alpha\log(x)}{(K+x^2)^2}\,dx =\frac{\pi K^{\frac{\alpha-3}{2}}}{8\cos\tfrac{\pi\alpha}{2}}\left[(1-\alpha)\log K+\pi(1-\alpha)\tan\tfrac{\pi\alpha}{2}-2\right].\tag{4}$$
By evaluating $(4)$ at $K=a^2$ and $\alpha=-\frac{1}{2}$ we get:
$$\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\log(x)}{\sqrt{x}(x^2+a^2)^2}\,dx =\frac{\pi |a|^{-7/2}}{4\sqrt{2}}\left[3\log|a|-\tfrac{3\pi}{2}-2\right].\tag{5}$$

Comment: @FrankW.: in order to reach an integral representation for the Beta function you need to enforce the substitution $x=\sqrt{K} z$, from which the half-integer exponent of $K$ in the closed form.

Comment: ’Aurizio Yeah I realized that soon after I posted my comment.

Answer (score 1):

Define $\sqrt{z}$ and $\ln z$ with a branch cut at the positive $x$-axis. Integrate $$f(z) = \frac{\ln z}{\sqrt{z}(z^2+a^2)^2}$$ around keyhole contour. along upper $x$-axis is :
$$\int_{\gamma_1} f(z) dz = \int_0^{\infty}\frac{\ln x}{\sqrt{x}(x^2+a^2)^2} dx$$
along lower $x$-axis is:
$$\int_{\gamma_2} f(z) dz = \int_\infty^{0}\frac{\ln x+2\pi i}{-\sqrt{x}(x^2+a^2)^2} dx = \int_0^{\infty}\frac{\ln x+2\pi i}{\sqrt{x}(x^2+a^2)^2} dx$$
from which you recovered the original integral.

Comment: So using this keyhole contour would mean 2 residues, both of order 2, would be included then?

Comment: You have to calculate the residue of $f(z)$ at $z=ai$ and $z=-ai$, and yes, they're both order $2$.

Comment: I get stuck when trying to evaluate $2\pi{i}\int_0^{\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}(x^2+a^2)^2}dx$. Is there a particular trick to integrating it?